# Level Order Successor of node in BST

Tags: algorithm

How can we find level order successor of a node in bst if parent pointer is given(with out using Queue ) ?

Comment: It's common practice to define the terms you use in a comp sci question, even if they are very well known. I for one am not familiar with the term "level order successor" as I've never heard it before, so can you please define it and maybe post an example?

Comment: @IVlad: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal see queue based level order traversal.

Comment: Level order successor means Successor of a node in Level order traversal

     5
  2      7
1   3   6  8  
   5         9    
the Level order travsersal is 5 2 7 1 3 6 5 9

So the level order successor of a node 5 is 9

Answer (score 0):

In the basic case, it's the right sibling of `node`.  Otherwise you need to wraparound to the next level, or return `No successor`.

Go up to the next parent with a right child, and traverse it left back down to level of `node`.  If you're able to trace back to `root` with no right children, go down the left side to `level + 1`.  If you reach an empty child ptr, return `no successor`.

If it's not a full BST, you may need to do a little more work - repeating until you find a node at the desired level.

Comment: It's fine.But I'm still thinking to do it in O(n) time and O(1) space

Comment: @dslap : this solution is O(n) time, O(1) space.

Comment: 2
13
  4
         5
           6
             7
Here your algorithm has to return 7 for LOS(6) .Will it do ?

There are so much cases to be considered like this